# Adding a constant to a closure expression

Tags: python, closures

I have a closure that takes some state variables and returns a function.

```
def function(state1,state2):
    def closure(variable):
        return state1*variable - state2*variable
    return closure
```

So now if I want to use this, I just do:

```
a = function(1,2)

a(10,20,30)
```

but now I want to do something slightly different so that I subtract a constant value from my closure function e.g.

```
a(10,20,30) - a(100)
```

What I really want to do is make a new function that does this:

```
def function2(subtract_value):
    return a - a(subtract_value)
```

but python doesn't let me subtract a float from a function object.

Does anyone know how I can do this without adding in the subtract_value option by hand to function 1?

Comment: `a(10,20,30)` will fail because the `closure` function accepts only one parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new function that wraps the closure function.

```
def make_subtract(fn, val):
    def wrapper(x):
        return fn(x) - val
    return wrapper
```

Then call it like this:

```
new_a = make_subtract(a, a(100))
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly what I wanted.

Is this somehow related to decorators?

Comment: I believe this is how to make decorators that can take options.